# Javascript browsing through photo-collection

Tags: javascript, php, html, photos

I would like to make a website where I can present some project of my client. He's an architect and wants his customers to be able to scroll through his buildings and projects.

Goal is to make a grid (3 wide, infinite long) of photos. In every square a project is displayed with max. 12 photos. I would like to display them in a way the users of the website can click on an image and scroll to the next one.
If the user clicks on another grid-item, the one he previously was clicking on, should stay in the same state (last shown photo) as it was before.

The photos are in a database and are coming in an `array` in the HTML (that's how to do it I guess, right?). I was thinking of using the URL as a reference to let the grid know which photo to show, but that's kind of useless since the grid-item has to remember his last state.

So I figured out Javascript is the way to go. I know a lot about HTML and PHP but my Javascript-skills aren't this sharp. Could anybody give me some advice or hits how to work this out?

[image]

Comment: Start making your way through jQuery tutorials. It's a great library that is quite easy to learn and use. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, great tip. You've got any tutorials in particular I should check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in the JQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)-plugin! Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 1):

This is a super simple sample. You don't even need jQuery and could do everything in Javascript only.

**Updated Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/qxpEz/2/

**Old sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/qxpEz/1/

For question regarding to jQuery you might want to check this out:
http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

**JS**

```
/* Close preview on click again */
$("#preview").live('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});

/* Handle click events on thumbnails */ 
$("img.thumbnail").live('click', function(){

    /* Build content for the preview DIV */
    $('#preview').html( '<img src="' + $('.last_viewed').attr("src") + '" />' );
    $('#preview').append( $(this).parent(".multi_row").html()  );

    /* Show images in larger size and show the preview DIV*/
    $('#preview .thumbnail').removeClass('thumbnail');
    $('#preview').show();

    // Set classes to identify the last clicked element
    $('.last_viewed').removeClass('last_viewed');
    $(this).addClass('last_viewed');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="preview"></div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="multi_row">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRi-8XnnXwAZmz_5R5LHRHMNlnYYHCP4WqRdu6vhf_ru8wLK9XB3IrNrwix" />
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlpPGwa7kTdYj4lraTh8-cUwLyPH8z78UxuwER1DvCK1IsgiB8A" />
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSDu5E2q1YEjN7EN2dlNUe81CQ6jVe_kcHrUSTRjB0PmG9wn5KA" />
    </div>

    <div class="multi_row">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvntvFejchqRwv41EqFxEqQAaFvc84xQB72LEmg0IZGM-KsfCZ" />        
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNMKqnVN0w6gemdm1DXlvCYhlx4DzK7XvyK2zJ2WaP86TUfKuF" />        
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLBVGB4YSU1ZSx4hTufNxcV8df_qOvHqCVPX9qqnwaFpKF0e9f" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Feel free to mention unclear parts or ask additional questions. I'll try to review them later on.

Comment: Ok, it's a great start, but not quite what I expected. I want a whole serie of photos to show every time I click and when clicking on an other image, the first image should stay on the photo last displayed.

Comment: @Michiel I updated the sample. I'm not sure if I understand you correct, but may this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/qxpEz/2/

Comment: thanks, you're getting close. Point is to display just one image on instant. The user can click on the image and it changes. So the site displays always just one image of a project. I'll try to make a drawing to enforce my intensions :-)

Comment: I hope you'll see what I want to achieve by my fabulous painting :)